# Keyfob decode using GNU Radio Companion

Tags: rf, demodulation, software-defined-radio, amplitude-modulation

Found this project to decode Hella Keyfobs

https://github.com/bastibl/gr-keyfob

Try to decode mine, but somehow the signal is way different from the one from the above Repo.

From the repo:
[image]

Mine:
[image]

As you can generally see first from the repo seems like 2 repeated frames with small break in between, second one is a longer frame with no break visible.

How to decode it? How to adjust GNU Radio Companion project specs?

I think frame start_packet by me is also "10101000".

First Decoded is:

```
gr::log :DEBUG: correlate_access_code_tag_bb0 - Access code: a8
gr::log :DEBUG: correlate_access_code_tag_bb0 - Mask: ff

IN:

[array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
       1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
       1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
       1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int8)]

Manchster:

0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0

IN:

[array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
       1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int8)]

Manchster:

0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1

gr::log :DEBUG: correlate_access_code_tag_bb0 - writing tag at sample 428

IN:

 [array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
       0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int8)]

Manchster:

1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

0000000428  01110001100000000  0b5bbc6cd7a466e6  0000101101011011101111000110110011010111101001000110011011100110  00011100  OPEN

IN:

[array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
       1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      dtype=int8)]

Manchster:

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0

gr::log :DEBUG: correlate_access_code_tag_bb0 - writing tag at sample 738


>>> Done
```

Using this GNU Radio project:

[image]

Comment: The project description says *"This is a GNU Radio module to receive and reencode signals **of (some) wireless car key fobs** from Hella."* Are you sure that yours is one of the "some" that are supported?

Comment: I guess not. Poking around this for a while and that's why I thought I look for help, especially since I am a beginner. Want to make sure that the GNU Radio Companion Project parses the whole frame, since I believe frame start is also at "10101000" .... but it is longer. Is this somewhere visible in GRC Project? Some block in a frame are repeats. There is a preamble 1010101 ... than packet_start and than data and i think again preamble, packet_start and data. If anybody is willing to help, I can provide more info. Looked at this in Inspectrum also manually, gathered a lot of info.